# Proving a certain inequality of infimums of upper Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

An assignment in Riemann's integral: Given two bounded function f and g in [a,b], if I proved that for every partition p:
$$
U(f+g,p) \leq U(f,p)+U(g,p)
$$

How can I show that:

**I don't know how to format this correctly but my intention is upper Riemann integral**
$$
\int_a^b f+g \leq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g
$$

I understand intuitively that if I proved the inequality for every p then it should also be true for the infimums of the groups holding the upper sums, but for some reason I can't manage to prove it on paper, something doesn't add up.

Would appreciate help on how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 1):

Take any partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ of $[a,b]$.  Let $P = P_1 \cup P_2$ be the common refinement.  We then have (using your first result)

$$U(f+g,P) \leqslant U(f,P) + U(g,P) \leqslant U(f,P_1) + U(g,P_2)$$

The upper (Darboux) integral of $f+g$ is given by

$$\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g) = \inf_{P' \in \mathcal{P}}\,U(f+g,P'),$$

wher $\mathcal {P}$ is the class of all partitions of $[a,b]$.

Thus,

$$\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g) \leqslant U(f+g,P) \leqslant U(f,P_1) + U(g,P_2)$$

Taking the infimum on the RHS over all $P_1 \in \mathcal{P}$ followed by the infimum over all $P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$, we get

$$\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g) \leqslant U(f+g,P) \leqslant \inf_{P_1 \in \mathcal{P}}U(f,P_1) + \inf_{P_2 \in \mathcal{P}}U(g,P_2) = \overline{\int_a^b} f + \overline{\int_a^b} g $$

Comment: The last part of your proof is actually where I've been struggling. How did you get from U(f+g,P)<=U(f,P1)+U(g,P2) to the same expression being smaller than the sum of two infomums?

Comment: @user3917631: With $P_1$ fixed, $\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g)  - U(f,P_1) \leqslant  U(g,P_2)$ and $\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g)  - U(f,P_1) $ is a lower bound for $U(g,P_2)$ as it ranges over all $P_2$. Thus,  $\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g)  - U(f,P_1) \leqslant  \inf_{P_2} U(g,P_2) = \overline{\int_a^b} g $, since   the RHS is the greatest lower bound.  Therefore $\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g) -  \overline{\int_a^b} g  \leqslant U(f,P_1) $. Now repeat the argument taking the infimum over all $U(f,P_1)$.

Comment: This yields $\overline{\int_a^b} (f+g) -  \overline{\int_a^b} g  \leqslant \overline{\int_a^b} f$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now.

Comment: (As I can no longer edit the previous comment)
$$\int_a^b f+g - U(g,p2) \le \int_a^b f$$


$$ \int_a^b f+g - U(f,p1) \le \int_a^b g$$

Comment: @user3917631: Is it clear to you now?  Note that partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ can be chosen independently.